# how to mak dialogue box untitled?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to create a dialog without a title and without white background

this my layoute

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Image"
        android:id="@+id/fondBoxWin" />
```

[I got the figure 1 And I want to get Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mekB.png)

and this my code java

```
 @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int identifiant) {
    Dialog box = null;
    //En fonction de l'identifiant de la boîte qu'on veut créer
    switch(identifiant) {
        case MY_BOX :
            box = new Dialog(this);
            box.setContentView(R.layout.mybox);
            break;
    }
    return box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a custom dialog , you have to make the `setBackgroundDrawable`  TRANSPARENT and `WindowFeature` NO TITLE . like this:

```
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(yourActivity.this);
    d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new   ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    d.setContentView(R.layout.yourDialogLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

In alert dialog, just pass null as the parameter when using

```
setTitle()
```

OR

just put

```
setTitle("");
```

(this is very unprofessional)